# How to connect my Java web application to database dataSource?

Tags: java, sql, database, wildfly, datasource

I configured a datasource in my Wildfly server with JNDI name java:/Postgres.

```
JNDI Name java:/Postgres
Driver Name postgresql-42.2.23.jar
Connection URL jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/skistuff
Enabled true
Statistics Enabled false
```

I also have a java web application that is supposed to connect to this database. I can connect to it with configuration below and everything works fine, but I have to use a datasource.

```
<sql:setDataSource                    
  var = "myDS"                                           
  driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/skistuff"
  user = "fred" 
  password = "secret"
/>
<sql:query var = "listStuff" dataSource = "${myDS}"> 
  SELECT * FROM skisEtc ORDER BY id;
</sql:query>
```

Documentation about setDataSource says there is an attribute "dataSource" that takes JNDI name. When I try it like an example below and then deploy it on my Wildfly server, I get an error that says "Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for java:/Postgres" "

```
<sql:setDataSource
  var = "myDS"
  driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  dataSource="java:/Postgres"
/>
<sql:query var = "listStuff" dataSource = "${myDS}">
  SELECT * FROM skisEtc ORDER BY id;
</sql:query>
```

What driver am I supposed to use? Or how can I connect my applicaction to the datasource?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the `driver` property? That is only relevant when using `url`. The error suggests to me it was generated by having `java:/Postgres` in the `url` field, not the `dataSource` field. Some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/setDataSource.html) suggests that datasource name should be 'relative', so also try `Postgres` (and maybe `/Postgres`).

Comment: I can't recall every using JSTL, but a cursory search also suggests you could do without using `setDataSource` and use the JNDI reference directly in `dataSource` in query.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried to delete setDataSource block at all and put JNDI name in <sql:query like this
<sql:query var = "listStuff" dataSource = "java:/Postgres">